# using find() on an unordered map<string,vector<string> > takes same time as ordered map in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, unordered-map

I have an unordered map of string and vector of strings i.e. `un_map<string,vector<string> >`.
While searching for a particular string using find function:

```
find((un_map[A].begin(),un_map[A].end(),field)==un_map[A].end())
```

The time of execution of find function for unordered map and ordered map comes the same. Can anyone explain why so? As far I know unordered map should be much faster than ordered map because of hashing. I want to optimize the find function. Please help

Answer (score 5):

[`std::find`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is searching using standard iteration over all container, using only incrementation of iterators. So, complexity here is O(n).

To speed-up finding element, based on container, you need to call `find` method of container.

[`std::unordered_map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) search complexity of O(1), because, as you pointed, it uses hashing.

[`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) search complexity is O(log(n)), because it uses binary search.